# Serial communication between telemetry radios

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have been searching for days what kind of mistake I made, but it is becoming impossible to find the solution to my error. I hope you will help me, thanks.

I am using the following antennas([https://www.amazon.com/Conjunto-telemetria-radio-SODIAL-3DROBOTICS/dp/B01EIYFFN0/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1530536680&sr=8-2-fkmr0&keywords=3dr+telemetry+radio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EIYFFN0)) to receive  strings into the raspberry and transmit a string through a macbook. The thing is that I don't get any transmitted string.

The MacBook code is the following:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/tty.usbserial-AH01W3BD",
    baudrate=57600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    xonxoff=True
    )

print "START SENDING"

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    ser.write(bytes("hello world"))
    print("Outputting transmiter buffer: " + str(ser.out_waiting))
    print("Outputting reciver buffer: " + str(ser.in_waiting))
```

The output of this code in the Mac is the following:

```
START SENDING
Outputting transmiter buffer: 0
Outputting reciver buffer: 0
Outputting transmiter buffer: 0
Outputting reciver buffer: 8
Outputting transmiter buffer: 0
Outputting reciver buffer: 16
Outputting transmiter buffer: 0
Outputting reciver buffer: 24
```

The raspy code:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/ttyAMA0",
    baudrate=57600,
    timeout=4,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    xonxoff=True
    )

print ("SETUP")
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    print ("START")
    print(ser.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

The output of the raspy code:

```
SETUP
START

START

START

START
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying any type of communication between 2 devices I would make sure that my setup per device is functional in the first place. It is easier to locate an issue in that way. So I would recommend to check if your raspi is transmiting and receiving first(you can connect the rx-tx pin as a simple test), so you can check that off the list. Also check that decoding for just in case.

2nd:

Then where VERY likely is the issue check your code running on the MAC, because it seems you are not transmitting(transmit buffer 0?). Is this the correct port? Why do you have a receive if your task is only to transmit(print("Outputting reciver buffer: " + str(ser.in_waiting))) ???? You are trying to transmit yet your receive buffer is increasing in size? Am I misunderstanding something? What python version is this, 2.7 or 3.6?

Comment: I just put the ser.in_waiting to see I was missing something and the python version is 2.7. I am also surprised with the transmitter and receiver buffer

Comment: To see the port on the Mac I use the command shell   ls /dev before connecting the antenna and ls. /dev after connecting the antenna and the only new port that appears is /dev/tty.usbserial-AH01W3BD

Comment: Lets try something. I think your issue might be in the way you handle the data. In the reading part you have a stream of bytes coming from the transmitter module(your MAC). Try to remove the bytes part in this (ser.write(bytes("hello world"))) and check if there is a change in the result in both modules. if the uart setup is correct then the issue is in the way you handle the data. Keep me updated.
ALSO check the port on the raspi

Comment: I have achieved something. The antennas have by default a protocol called Mavlink, this protocol interfered in the way the information was received, for example, if I wanted to send hello world, I received something different, so the solution to this problem was setting Rawdata as a protocol in the 3dr software (a software to configure the antennas). Another problem that I had is the permissions to read serial port which was /dev/ttyS0 and not /dev/ttyAMA0. Now the problem is that I am not able to give permanent permissions to read the serial port.

Comment: I have tried the following: sudo chmod +777 /dev/ttyS0, sudo adduser $USER dialout, KERNEL=="tty[A-Z]*[0-9]|pppox[0-9]*|ircomm[0-9]*|noz[0-9]*|rfcomm[0-9]*", GROUP="dialout", sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi and sudo nano /etc/rc.local, I wrote sudo chmod +777 /dev/ttyS0 in /etc/rc.local but nothing changed the file permissions of /dev/ttyS0. Could anyone give me another solution ?

Comment: Good to hear you have improvement! I am pretty sure there is a lot of info which you can find on the web regarding your permission issue. Anyway I think you should start a new topic since this is a question requiring a Linux experienced user and your serial com issue is solved. :)